# Signed Extensions AdditionalSigned associated type

Tags: transactions, signed-extensions

When reading about Signed Extensions in the [transaction-format](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/transaction-format/) post it states that AdditionalSigned can be used to

> to handle any additional data to go into the signed payload. This makes it possible to attach any custom logic prior to dispatching a transaction.

I noticed that [CheckGenesis](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/system/src/extensions/check_genesis.rs) uses it but no clear on how it works.

Can you please explain how AdditionalSigned works and provide some additional use cases of AdditionalSigned?

Also, what does it mean by "attach any custom logic prior to dispatching a transaction"? How is it different than pre-dispatch and when should I use it over pre-dispatch?

Answer (score 1):

The point of `AdditionalSigned` to include data in the signed data, aka the data is given to the `sign` function and is being "secured" by the signature of the transaction. The nice property of `AdditionalSigned` is that this data isn't part of the transaction itself. This means it doesn't increase the size of the transaction. However, this also means it needs to be data that both sides (signer and the chain) are aware of. An example of this is the genesis hash as you already said or the the `spec_version`.

`CheckGenesis` is for example used to protect against replays of transactions on different chains as they all have a different genesis. `CheckSpecVersion` is used to invalidate all transactions after a runtime upgrade, because the `Call` format may changed and you don't want to apply "invalid" calls.